# Replace delimiter symbols in Arev Sans for proper scaling

Tags: beamer, delimiters, arev

[Edited to expand question]

I'm using Arev Sans for presentations with Beamer but the default parentheses in math bother me. The smallest sets don't match well the next larger stretched sets. In addition, they don't match the delimiters used in text mode This example shows how they are a bit too heavy:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{arev}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Normal text delimiters vs. math delimiters
\[
\text{(a)} \quad \left( a \right) \qquad
\text{[a]} \quad \left[ a \right] \qquad
\text{\{a\}} \quad \left\{ a \right\}
\]

\item Different sized math delimiters
\[
\left( a \right) \quad \left( a^2 \right) \qquad 
\left[ a \right] \quad \left[ a^2 \right] \qquad
\left\{ a \right\} \quad \left\{ a^2 \right\}
\]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to replace the smallest sets of math delimiters by the ones used in regular text so they match the larger ones better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED to avoid scaling approach, and stick to pure strut-based approach.

If one wished a fully automated version of the approach, so that `\fixdelim` is auto-applied to all instances of `\left`, here is such an approach that involves no scaling, but only the presence of an additional strut automatically inserted into each expression of `\left...\right`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{arev}
\def\mystrut{\protect\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}}
\def\fixdelim\svleft#1#2\right#3{\svleft#1\mystrut #2\right#3}
\let\svleft\left
\def\left{\fixdelim\svleft}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\left( g \right) \quad \left( g^2 \right) \qquad 
\left( a \right) \quad \left( a^2 \right) \qquad 
\left[ a \right] \quad \left[ a^2 \right] \qquad
\left\{ a \right\} \quad \left\{ a^2 \right\}
\]
\[
\left(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\right)_{\left[\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right]}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**VARIATION ON ORIGINAL APPROACH**

This method uses a scaling procedure, instead of mere struts.

This requires `\fixdelim` to be manually added before `\left`, `(`, `[`, or `\{`, when needed. It works in text and math mode, but can fail for smaller math styles.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{arev,scalerel}
%\def\mystrut{\protect\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}}
\def\mystrut{\protect\rule{0pt}{1.4\LMex}}
\def\fixdelim#1{\ifx\left#1\expandafter\fixdelimA\expandafter#1\else
    \ifmmode
      \ifx(#1\expandafter\fixdelimE\expandafter#1\else
      \ifx[#1\expandafter\fixdelimF\expandafter#1\else
      \ifx\{#1\expandafter\fixdelimG\expandafter#1\fi\fi\fi
    \else
      \ifx(#1\expandafter\fixdelimB\expandafter#1\else
      \ifx[#1\expandafter\fixdelimC\expandafter#1\else
      \ifx\{#1\expandafter\fixdelimD\expandafter#1\fi\fi\fi
    \fi
  \fi}
\def\fixdelimA\left#1#2\right#3{\ThisStyle{\scalebox{1}[.9]{$\SavedStyle%
  \left#1\scalebox{1}[1.111]{$\SavedStyle\mystrut #2$}\right#3$}}}
\def\fixdelimB(#1){$\fixdelimA\left(\right.$#1$\fixdelimA\left.\right)$}
\def\fixdelimC[#1]{$\fixdelimA\left[\right.$#1$\fixdelimA\left.\right]$}
\def\fixdelimD\{#1\}{$\fixdelimA\left\{\right.$#1$\fixdelimA\left.\right\}$}
\def\fixdelimE(#1){\fixdelimA\left(\right.\!#1\!\fixdelimA\left.\right)}
\def\fixdelimF[#1]{\fixdelimA\left[\right.\!#1\!\fixdelimA\left.\right]}
\def\fixdelimG\{#1\}{\fixdelimA\left\{\right.\!#1\!\fixdelimA\left.\right\}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Text mode: \fixdelim(xyz)
\fixdelim[xyz]
\fixdelim\{xyz\}

Math Mode:
\[
\fixdelim(a)
\fixdelim[a]
\fixdelim\{a\}
\]
\[
\fixdelim\left( a \right) \quad \left( a^2 \right) \qquad 
\fixdelim\left[ a \right] \quad \left[ a^2 \right] \qquad
\fixdelim\left\{ a \right\} \quad \left\{ a^2 \right\}
\]
\[
\scriptscriptstyle\fixdelim(a)
\fixdelim[a]
\fixdelim\{a\}
\]
Doesn't always work in smaller math styles
\[
\scriptscriptstyle
\fixdelim\left( a \right) \quad \fixdelim\left( a^2 \right) \qquad 
\fixdelim\left[ a \right] \quad \fixdelim\left[ a^2 \right] \qquad
\fixdelim\left\{ a \right\} \quad \fixdelim\left\{ a^2 \right\}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice approach but it would be nice to have a delimiter size smaller than \big and it should match the delimiter used in text mode (I realize that this was not part of my original question -- will edit.)

Comment: @Thomsa I re-added my original approach, which takes care of the first issue.  However, it is a manual approach.

Comment: @Thomsa I have modified my original approach to handle text mode, and the use of these symbols absent the `\left...\right` mode.  It still has some issues.

Comment: it seems that replacing the symbol used for the normal-sized delimiter in math mode by the symbol used in text mode would be a simpler solution.